# Should I use "to" or "for" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Drinking milk. To most people, it helped them to sleep; **to/for** her, it
>   caused the opposite.

Should it be **to** or **for** and why?

Comment: It's "to most people" then it's "to her". The sentence is a bit odd. Why "it helped them"?

Comment: @SovereignSun Milk help most people to sleep.

Comment: "To most people it helped them to sleep" sounds wrong to this US English speaker.  It should be **for** for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern *to X, Y* means that X appears to be Y to X, but X has not necessarily consumed, tried, or used Y.

> To most people, it helped them to sleep

This sounds like that most people saw something X, and observed that it helped a group of other people to sleep.  Since you are talking about drinking milk, it's unlikely you want to express this.

*For X, Y* would be used if X actually consumed, tried, or used Y.

Your sentence probably really wants to be this:

> Drinking milk - *for* most people, it helped them to sleep; *but for* her, it caused the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

**To most people** sounds like *"to their knowledge"*

The correct preposition would be **"for"**:

- Drinking milk. For most people it helped sleep; for her, it caused the opposite.

*"To most people, it helped them to sleep"* - **"them"** and **"to"** are superfluous. And no comma is needed.